# Get from the windows system the user email registered from cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

do you know how to retrieve from the windows system the email with which the user registered in the operating system? When you create an account, windows asks you for an email to register. Is it possible to retrieve that information via code line, cmd or who knows what else?

Comment: Why? And with hacks it is still possible to not register, even with Windows 11.

Comment: @Anders all people are not hackers...

Comment: No put you have to keep in mind for whatever you are doing that there might not be an email. Why do you need this address again?

Comment: I'm not a hacker, @iose, and I certainly have never installed a version of Windows, using an email address. I have always created local accounts with self chosen user names.

Comment: @Compo and so? Another question was asked...

Answer (score 0):

*I got a customer PC in today which actually had a single account which was created using an email address. The only possibilities I could find were by trying to retrieve the email address via the Windows registry.*

This first idea was to see if the user account still had the default OneDrive account attributed to that email. So based upon that as a possibility you could try to isolate it from the User registry branch.

From the Command Prompt:

```bash
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Personal" /V "UserEmail" 2^>NUL') Do @Echo(%H
```

From a batch file:

```bash
@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Personal" /V "UserEmail" 2^>NUL') Do @Echo(%%H
```

---

Alternatively you'd have to use the Machine registry branch, which would list all found. This however would only identify the current user if theirs was the only account on that machine which had been created to log in with an email address created account. If there are more than one, then it would list them all.

From the Command Prompt:

```bash
For /F "Delims=" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IdentityStore\LogonCache" /S /F "Name2Sid" /K 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "HKEY_"') Do @For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%G" /S /V "IdentityName" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "@"') Do @Echo(%I
```

From a batch file:

```bash
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IdentityStore\LogonCache" /S /F "Name2Sid" /K 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "HKEY_"') Do @For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "%%G" /S /V "IdentityName" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "@"') Do @Echo(%%I
```

---

*Please note, as per the comment section, the majority of user's computers I've worked on, and that is a very large number, do not have user accounts created using an email address, and the above examples would be unlikely to perform the task you require.*